# Where is the correct place to set net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets?

Tags: centos6, sysctl, conntrack, nf-conntrack

I'm currently trying to set net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets on boot.  I initially assumed that this could be done through sysctl.conf, but net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets (and other net.netfilter configurations) were not applied at all.  Adding sysctl -p to rc.local allowed all the net.netfilter configurations to be applied with the exception of net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets.  I'll also note that trying to set this from the terminal using sysctl -w results in 'error: permission denied on key 'net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets''

```
# This should be applied at boot
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=1966080
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets=245760
```

Where is the correct place to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that sysctl parameter is for viewing only. You'll want to use the `/sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize` interface for runtime changes, and the `hashsize` module option to set it during initial module load.

You'd want an entry in a `/etc/modprobe.d/` file that looks something like this:

`options nf_conntrack hashsize=XXXXX`

Comment: I have noticed that if you set the hashsize via /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize the net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets sysctl is not updated, while if you do it via modprobe and then reboot it is changed. Does that mean that changing the value via the first method doesn't completely apply the new value?

Answer (score 5):

Further to Andrew B's answer:

For some reason, the [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Persistent_Module_Loading.html) recommends putting an executable shell script with a name like `nf_conntrack_hashsize.modules` extension into `/etc/sysconfig/modules` instead. I have no idea why. Contents would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /sbin/modprobe nf_conntrack hashsize=262144
```

Comment: Seems like this is needed if you want to load additional modules which wouldn't have been loaded otherwise. [quote] You can specify additional modules to be loaded by creating a new <file_name>.modules[/quote]

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a file called, for example, localhost inside /etc/modprobe.d/ directory.

Inside this file, add these lines (value is an example):

```
options nf_conntrack hashsize=333333
```

And now, the more quick solution is a restart, the other option is to try a reload the nf_conntrack kernel module, wich is a bit difficult because it's linked with others running modules.

Check the result with:

```
cat /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize
```